# How does Objective-C messaging work? Where is `super`? How to make sure a class has an implementation from its super before method swizzling?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, message-forwarding

I have some question about Obj-C message.

#### (1) It's my main question: how to make sure a class has an implementation from its superclass before swizzling it or invoking it?

If I want to do method swizzling with a method which the target class didn't implement it, but its superclass did, how to make sure this class has the implementation from its superclass before method swizzling?

I know when a message sent to an object which did not implement it, the Obj-C runtime will first look up its inherit hierarchy to find the implementation from its superclass. If there is one, Obj-C will cache it in a different dispatch table and invoke it.

Can I do method swizzling with this cached implementation? If can, how to make sure there is an cached implementation before method swizzling or sending any message to this object? If not, how to add a *real* implementation to this class which will just invoke the `super`'s implementation before method swizzling?

For example, there is a class hierarchy like this:

```
@interface A : NSObject
- (void) helloWorld;
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@interface C : B
@end

@interface D : C
@end

@interface E : D
@end
```

and the implementation like this:

```
@implemenation A
- (void) helloWorld{
    NSLog(@"hello world from class A");
}
@end

@implemenation B
// did not override -helloWorld
@end

@implemenation C
- (void) helloWorld{
    [super helloWorld];
    NSLog(@"hello world from class C");
}
@end

@implemenation D
// did not override -helloWorld
@end

@implemenation E
// did not override -helloWorld
@end
```

I want to just exactly exchange (not adding) the implementation of `-helloWorld` with the Class `D` at runtime. This trick will add an additional task to the original implementation if the swizzled method like this:

```
@implemenation D (AdditionalWorkForHelloWorld)
- (void) additionalWorkForHelloWorld{
    [self additionalWorkForHelloWorld];
    NSLog(@"hello every one!");
}
@end
```

So when I send a `-helloWorld` message to the instance of Class `D` or Class `E`, the console will print the following messages:

```
-> hello world from class A
-> hello world from class C
-> hello every one!
```

Someday, after the class `D` implements its `-helloWorld` as following:

```
@implemenation D
- (void) helloWorld{
    [super helloWorld];
    NSLog(@"hello world from class D");
}
@end
```

and send a `-helloWorld` message to the instance of Class `D` or Class `E`, the console will print the following messages:

```
-> hello world from class A
-> hello world from class C
-> hello world from class D
-> hello every one!
```

This method exchanging will make sure the additional task will be invoked whether class `D` implements `-helloWorld` or not.

I'v [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319489/how-to-write-c-function-which-invoke-supers-implementation-in-objective-c) about how to make a C function to invoke an object's `super`'s implementation, and it seems not easy to do that. How does Obj-C achieve this cached mechanism to forward the message to `super`'s implementation?

#### (2) How dose Obj-C handle `super` keyword? and where is `super`?

In the Obj-C message, the first two arguments are hidden: `self` and `_cmd`. You can use them in an Obj-C implementation. But where is `super`?

Is a `super` equal to the `self`'s `isa` pointer? How dose Obj-C handle `super` keyword?

Every Obj-C message will convert to `objc_msgSend()` or `objc_msgSend_stret()`. So does every message sent to `super` will convert to `objc_msgSendSuper()` and `objc_msgSendSuper_stret()`?

In the example mentioned previously, when I send a `-helloWorld` message to the Class `E`, and Class `D` and `E` don't respond it, Obj-C will send the message to Class `C`'s implementation. In the Class `C`'s implementation, it invokes its `super`'s implementation, but Class `B` did not implement it, so forward it to Class `A`.

In this case, the `super` of Class `C` should be Class `B`, so it actually invokes Class `B`'s cached implementation, doesn't it? May I swizzle the Class `B`'s cached implementation?

Comment: 1) "Messaging" is (a rather complex form of) simply "calling" in any other language.  2) If your class is a subclass of any other class it has a "super".  Using "super" in an invocation simply clues the compiler to look for the superclass version of the named method.  You should know what the class is you subclassed and what methods it supports, hence what methods you can use "super" to invoke.

Comment: If this isn't making much sense you probably need to study up more on classes and class inheritance.

Comment: As close as I can understand your description of how `additionalWorkForHelloWorld` should work, that's not readily possible in Objective-C (though Objective-C has many features that allow "impossible" things to be done with some difficulty).  (And, BTW, your implementation of that method would suffer from infinite recursion.)

Comment: (Well, actually it is possible.  Just implement `helloWorld` in D, have it invoke the `super` version, *then* have it print your added message.)

Comment: Sometimes, the Class `D` is not really implemented by you. If I want to add an extra code to the target method, and I don't know this implementation would be implemented by this class or its superclass, I need to check at runtime. If it is not implemented by the class itself, I should add an implementation before exchanging them.

Comment: In terms of calling a "super" method it makes no difference whether the method is implemented in the immediately "super" class or its "super" or its "super" -- the check is done recursively until either the "bottom" is reached or a matching method is found.  In terms of "intercepting" a call to a method not in your class, there are ways to do this but they are graduate level interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A message to `super` is sent to `self`. However, the lookup of the implementation starts at a different place. When you message `self`, the Objective-C run time (`objc_msgSend()`, etc.) looks first in the class pointed to by `self`'s `isa` pointer. If no implementation is found there, the search moves to the superclass, and so on.

When you message `super`, the search starts in the superclass of the class whose code contained the invocation of `super`. Yes, the message to `super` translates into a call to `objc_msgSendSuper()` or one of its variants. The compiler constructs an `objc_super` structure that contains `self` and the superclass of the class currently being compiled. (Note: that's *not* the same as `[self superclass]`. That expression is dynamic and depends on the actual class of `self`. The superclass targeted by a message to `super` is not dynamic and doesn't depend on the actual class of `self`.)

Anyway, `objc_msgSendSuper()` uses the superclass referenced in the `objc_super` structure to control where it starts the search for the implementation, but otherwise behaves like `objc_msgSend()`. That's it. That's all that `super` does: it starts the search for the implementation further along the chain of classes.

As to how to accomplish your swizzling goal… I think you want to first try adding an implementation that calls `super`. If that fails (because the class already has such a method), then swizzle in a different implementation that calls the original.

So, something like:

```
@implemenation D (AdditionalWorkForHelloWorld)
- (void) addedHelloWorldIfNotPresent{
    [super helloWorld];
    NSLog(@"hello every one!");
}
- (void) additionalWorkForHelloWorld{
    [self additionalWorkForHelloWorld];
    NSLog(@"hello every one!");
}
@end
```

Then try adding the implementation of `-addedHelloWorldIfNotPresent` using `class_addMethod()`. Obtain the implementation using `+[NSObject instanceMethodForSelector:]` with `@selector(addedHelloWorldIfNotPresent)`. If adding the method fails, then swizzle in `-additionalWorkForHelloWorld` for the existing `-helloWorld`, instead.